# Facebook Graph API - Search for Work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I noticed the "/Search" works only on "Names". How would it be possible to search Facebook user's programmatically, by searching their "Work".

For instance, I want to search for all users who work "web development". Is this available?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the current time. The [Graph API documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) states that the format for searches is `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY&type=OBJECT_TYPE`, which does not allow for any granularity in search parameters.

Note that **user searches do not only work with names** - if you do a search for a non-name term, like "programming", you will likely receive results for profiles who do not contain the term in their names. Depending on their privacy settings, it might be impossible to use the API to figure out why they are showing up for this term.

A possible alternate solution would be to request the `friends_work_history` permission from your users and manually search through their work history. Note that this would only help you search a user's friends' work history (and not all users' work history), and that you would restricted by the [Platform Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) on how you could use this data.